# Can I put two loads on one battery and both loads draw 3.7v as they expect?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, lipo

I have a project in mind where I replace the tinny 40mAh LiPO battery of a "smart band" (Like a Mi Band 1) and replace it with a regular 18650 LiPo battery, so it last a long time without recharging. That would be simple, but what about if I have two of them?

My plan is to wire the battery to a [TC4056A 1A battery charging board](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32836729294.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.274263c0QqV5g0), and the loads in **parallel**.

[image]

I've been told by a friend that that's fine, but I have absolutely zero formal training in electrical engineering and I'm unsure about what I'm doing... that's where I ask you. :)

Also, would you change something to make the circuit better and/or safer?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: I was afraid if by connecting the devices like that they would draw 1,85V... but that would be if I connected them in series, right?

Comment: The devices don't "draw" voltage, they draw current. If you connect two loads in parallel they draw twice as much current as a single load would do. The voltage remains the same as it's a characteristic of the battery. You attempt probably is fine, but you might want to look at the current draw of your loads.